# Overlapping label and text in description environment

Tags: spacing, horizontal-alignment, lists, description

I'm relatively new to LaTeX, and I am having this problem with the description environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{IEEEtrantools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\begin{document}
\begin{description}
    \item[this:] this is a description that isn't messed up.
    \item [sll kjsl kslkdfjl f:] but there really is a problem with this one, isn't there?
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

produces

[image: this output]

As far as I can tell I have good syntax, but I have a hard time believing that this is the default behavior of the LaTeX renderer.

Extra notes:

- If you'll notice, the description isn't bold, either.
- The fact that the sentence that follows is in math mode seems to be irrelevant.
- I'm using pdfLaTeX, but the behavior is the same regardless of the rendering method used.!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx). The question is ok, just extend your preamble into a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) and it will be just perfect! One question: you use `enumitem` package or not? It is commented in your preamble, and it obviously does a big difference!

Comment: Actually, I've already solved the problem, but this site is biased against noobs (for good reason) so I couldn't answer it. I was not using the `enumitem` package, and my problem was the use of the `IEEEtrantools` package without the `retainorgcmds` option. I'll fix up the question.

Comment: @SegFaultsMcGee I closed (for now) as too localized (specific error situation) and solved. If you still would like to add an answer, just notify me, I could reopen it.